# extjs 3.4 how to dynamically add checkbox to toolbar

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs3

I have Panel with a `BottomToolbar`. I want to add and remove dynamically a `checkbox/checkboxgroup` or `radio/radiogroup`. I saw that we have the method `addItem` for `Ext.Toolbar` but the checkbox doesn't extends Item... Is there a way to accomplish this?

A preview of my code and what I want to achieve:

```
var myCheckboxGroup = new Ext.form.CheckboxGroup({
        id:'displayParamCheckGroup',
        xtype: 'checkboxgroup',
        columns: 1,
        items: checkboxArray
    });
Ext.getCmp('siteChartPanel').getBottomToolbar().add(myCheckboxGroup);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have forgotten to call doLayout() method after adding:

```
Ext.getCmp('siteChartPanel').getBottomToolbar().doLayout();
```